# C# Winform or WPF word-like page component

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know of a C# WinForm or WPFcomponent that I can use as a "Word-Blank-page" control?
I need that the my user at runtime see a whit-blank-page that can manipulate by having basic text editing (bold, fonts, color), basic tables and images placed everywhere on the "canvas" (the white page).
The component should give me an API, so I can react on user actions on the component, like when right clicking on table or an image (I will display different forms depending on the object clicked).

I look for some extension of the RichTextEdit control from different vendors, but any of those can give me the functionality I need.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Flow documents is a good way to go. They are [thoroughly documented by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx).

They provide all the functionality you mentioned and then some. Code Project has some good examples on how to use flow documents. You can check [this beginners guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners) for starters.

Comment: After a long evaluation, I decided to go with this one for price & functionality: http://www.subsystems.com/tewf.htm

Comment: Its kinda pricey for an edit control at $650/platform/developer but if it feels right for you, I don't see why not.

Comment: Do you have another recommendation?? I tried DevExpress and TX Text control.